# Google Charts axis order

Tags: google-visualization

I am using Google Charts in my project where I get data from the controller as in Model Attribute. But when I see the Line Chart the x-axis comes in a reverse order.
Here's what I did:

```
var data4 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data4.addColumn('string', 'Date');
    data4.addColumn('number','Balance');


    <c:forEach var="details" items="${details}">
        data4.addRow(["${details.date}", ${details.amount}]); 
    </c:forEach>

var options4 = {
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
      title: 'Amount',
      hAxis: {  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}, direction:-1, slantedText:true, slantedTextAngle:45},
      vAxis: {minValue: 1000}, 
    };`

var chart4 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart4'));
chart4.draw(data4, options4);
```

I get date in x-axis but in the reverse order in which it is added in the rows. I think adding of rows is like adding at the start not appending, How do I make it in the right order?
Can anyone help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: dates will result in a continuous axis, the chart will sort automatically. use a string for a discrete axis -- see [discrete vs continuous](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#discrete-vs-continuous)

Comment: Thanks Man. It works!!